# How to execute server side function in html view on node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm coming from PHP (laravel), I'm still new to node.js and its being fun but i have some issues with using server side functions in my html view. Unlike in laravel, where i have access to some important server side functions that makes work faster by avoiding repetitions in my view, i don't seem to have access to server side functions in node.js (express).
In laravel  i can do these in my views:

```
asset('images/avatar.jpg')
config('app.name') 
url('users/posts')
```

In laravel, my images and other files are in **storage directory** which is not in the public directory but using the **asset()** function in blade template, i can access files in storage folder.

In my current node.js app, i have a pathConfig.json file that contains my app path settings, At the server side I can access the file, how can i access the same path from my view ?
I'm using **express** with **handlebars**

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten exactly what i wanted using express-handlebars' custom helper...
With express-handlebars, i can write my function at the server side and use it in the view.

**I have a helper.js file at the server side**

```
const url = function(link=false) {
    return process.env.URL+'/'+link;
};


const anotherFunction = function() {
    return 2+2;
};

module.exports = {
    url : url,
    anotherFunction : anotherFunction
};
```

**App.js file**

```
helpers  = require('./helpers.js');    

app.engine('.html', hbs({
    extname : '.html',
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    helpers: helpers
}));
```

**In my view (index.html)**

```
<a href="{{url 'post/comments'}}"> Post comments</a>
```

Comment: +1, but this answer would be improved if you could give him an example of each of the helpers he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

create a `public` directory in which you will save all your assets `css, js, fonts, images`, after that you must set the `static` middleware which allow express to serve file that are store in some location

```
var app = express()

// attaching the static middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

if you have an image `test.png` store in the `images` subfolder of your public directory you can access that by using http://xxxxx:port_number/test.png